# Most performant way to load associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to load a nested association, a `User` can belong to many `Groups` and I want to load all `Posts` from `Groups` where the user is a member, but only the posts no the groups as well.

Something like `current_user.groups.eager_load(:posts)`, but without nesting posts under groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `Post` belongs to `Group` here.

Start with the model that you need to load and build the query from there. If user belongs to 2 groups here, this will load all the posts from those 2 groups.

```rb
Post.where(group: current_user.groups)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a shortcut from `User` to `Post` with [has_many :through](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association)

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  has_many :posts, through: :groups

  # if User already has a `has_many :posts`, you'll need 
  # to give the through-association a unique name like this:
  # has_many :group_posts, through: :groups, source: :posts
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group

  # optionally, you can define the inverse here as well
  # has_many :users, through: :group
end
...

# eager_load on a query: User.includes(:posts) or User.eager_load(:posts)
# get from current user: current_user.posts
```